# Prove that $D((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=max{d_x(x_1,x_2),d_y(y_1,y_2)}$ is a metric .

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to prove that $D((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=max (d_x(x_1,x_2),d_y(y_1,y_2)) $ is a  metric.

My idea is that if

$max (d_x(x_1,x_2),d_y(y_1,y_2))=d_x(x_1,x_2)$ then

$D((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=d_x(x_1,x_2)$ and $ d_x(x_1,x_2)$ is a metric which follows that $D((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ is a metric  , the same comes if

$max (d_x(x_1,x_2),d_y(y_1,y_2))=d_y(y_1,y_2)$ which follows that $D((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ is a metric.

I'm not sure if this is true or i need to prove the three conditions especially. Thanks for helping !

Comment: No this is not a proof, since you seem to be mainly playing with words. First, "$ d_x(x_1,x_2)$ is a metric" means nothing. Do you mean that $d_x$ is a metric? Then this cannot imply alone that $D$ is a metric, right?

Comment: ok the example is that if $d_x$ and $d_y$ are metrics prove that the given function D is a metric too . So according to your opinion i need to prove  step by step the three conditions for metric ?

Comment: Not an opinion but what is written: you need to prove that D is a metric and nothing in your post does this. Checking the three axioms would be a sure way to go.

Comment: Ok , I will try that way , thank you a lot .